# Using FusionCharts with Ext JS

Tags: extjs, wrapper, fusioncharts, extjs7

I am thinking about using FusionCharts in an application entirely build with Ext JS so far. 
However, I don't believe there's a specific recommended implementation or connector to easily add FusionCharts to an Ext JS app.  There are various examples online of others adding the charts within an Ext JS app though:

- http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/xujmxjcb/
- http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/5j8s7g68/
- https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?218834-How-to-integrate-fusion-charts-with-Extjs4&p=830921&viewfull=1#post830921

The last one discusses a way to create an Ext JS class for FusionCharts that "wraps" some of the charting functionality within a proper class:

```
/* * ?????? : var testdata = { part : { 'Jul 01' : 2000, 'Aug 02' : 2400, 'Sep 03' : 2000, 'Oct 04' :
 * "", 'Dec 05' : null }, zoo : { 'Jul 01' : 4000, 'Aug 02' : 3400, // 'Sep 03' : 3000, // 'Oct 04' :
 * 5200, 'Dec 05' : 4210 }, hotel : { // 'Jul 01' : 6000, 'Aug 02' : 6400, // 'Sep 03' : 7000, 'Oct
 * 04' : 8200, 'Dec 05' : 8100 } }; // this.setChartData(testdata); ????????????
 */


/**
 * ????
 * @class Ext.ux.MSLineChart
 * @extends Ext.Panel
 * @cgf initData : Object ??????.
 * @cgf DwrAction : DWR???? ??????.
 * @cgf baseLoadParam : Object DWR???????.
 * @cgf autoShowChart : boolean ??(true) ??????????.
 * @function loadData() : ??DWR????,????.
 * @cgf imageType ???? : MSColumn2D,MSColumn3D,MSLine,MSArea,MSBar2D,MSBar3D StackedColumn2D,
 * StackedColumn3D,StackedArea2D,StackedBar2D,StackedBar2D,StackedBar3D
 */


Ext.ux.FusionChart = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
      width : 1000,
      height : 600,
      border : false,
      layout : 'fit',
      autoShowChart : true,
      animationflex : true,
      imageType : 'MSLine',


      constructor : function(config) {
          Ext.apply(this, config);


          this.isLineChart = true; // ??????????
          var chartDom = Ext.core.DomHelper.append(document.body, {
                id : 'ux-fc-' + ++Ext.AbstractComponent.AUTO_ID,
                tag : 'div',
                cls : 'x-hidden',
                style : 'z-index:-1;width:100%;height:100%'
            });


          this.chart = new FusionCharts(WEBPATH + '/common/fc/' + this.imageType + '.swf', chartDom.id, '100%', "100%", "0",
            "1", null);
          this.chart.addParam("wmode", "transparent");// ???,????EXT


          if (this.initData) {
              this.setChartData(this.initData);
          } else if (this.DwrAction && this.autoShowChart === true) {
              this.loadData(this.baseLoadParam);
          }
          this.contentEl = this.chart.getAttribute('id');
          Ext.ux.FusionChart.superclass.constructor.call(this);
          this.on('render', this.renderPanel, this);


      },


      renderPanel : function() {


      },


      /** ??DWR??????. */
      loadData : function(param) {
          param = param || {};
          Ext.applyIf(param, this.baseLoadParam);
          var setChartData = Ext.bind(this.setChartData, this);
          this.DwrAction(param, setChartData);
      },


      // ??????XML???render chart
      setChartData : function(data) {
          var animation = this.animationflex == true ? 1 : 0;
          var DataXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<chart animation =\"" + animation
            + "\" baseFont=\"??\" baseFontSize=\"12\">";
          var valuePartXML = "", trendlinesXML = "";
          var xNameArray = [];


          if (data['trendlines']) { // ???(??:??,???), ????? : {?:??}
              trendlinesXML = "<trendlines> ";
              for (var key in data['trendlines']) {
                  trendlinesXML += "<line startValue='" + key + "' color='" + data['trendlines'][key].replace('#', '')
                    + "' displayValue='" + key + "' showOnTop='1' />";
              }
              trendlinesXML += "</trendlines>";
              delete data['trendlines'];
          }


          DataXML += "<categories>"
          for (var key in data) {
              if (key.length > 0) {
                  var record = data[key];
                  for (var xName in record) {
                      /* xNameArray.indexOf(xName) == -1 && */
                      if (xName && String(xName).length > 0) {
                          DataXML += "<category label=\"" + xName + "\"/>"; // x???
                          xNameArray.push(xName);
                      }
                  }
                  break; // ????, ???????????. (???????)
              }
          }
          DataXML += "</categories>";
          for (var key in data) { // ??
              if (key.length > 0) {
                  var record = data[key];
                  valuePartXML += "<dataset seriesName=\"" + key + "\">";
                  for (var i = 0; i < xNameArray.length; i++) {
                      var xName = xNameArray[i];
                      if (record[xName] && String(record[xName]).length > 0) {
                          valuePartXML += "<set value=\"" + record[xName] + "\"/>"; // x???
                      } else if (this.isLineChart == true) {
                          record[xName] = this.getEstimated(xName, record, xNameArray);
                          valuePartXML += "<set showValue =\"0\" toolText=\" \" displayValue=\" \"   value=\"" + record[xName] + "\"/>"; // x???
                      }
                  }
                  valuePartXML += "</dataset>";
              }
          }
          DataXML += valuePartXML + trendlinesXML;
          DataXML += "</chart>"
          this.chart.setDataXML(DataXML);
          this.chart.show(); // render
      },


      /** line????????,?????. */
      getEstimated : function(xName, record, xNameArray) {
          var front = null;
          var back = null;
          var space = 2;
          for (var i = xNameArray.indexOf(xName) - 1; i > -1; i--) {
              var currUp = record[xNameArray[i]];
              if (currUp != null && String(currUp).length > 0) {
                  front = Number(currUp);
                  break;
              }
              space++;
          }
          for (var i = xNameArray.indexOf(xName) + 1; i < xNameArray.length; i++) {
              var currDown = record[xNameArray[i]];
              if (currDown != null && String(currDown).length > 0) {
                  back = Number(currDown);
                  break;
              }
              space++;
          }
          if (front == null || back == null) {
              return null;
          } else {
              return (back - front) / space + front;
          }
      }


  })
```

What is the best way to proceed and what are the advantages/disadvantages?

Any help is greatly appreciated and sorry for the rookie question!
Best
/R

Comment: The 3rd code sample looks a bit outdated, but in general, that approach (wrapping it in a class) would be the best way to go. That way you can control the API to fusion charts through the Ext component so it fits cohesively with your app.

Comment: The FusionCharts code written would work with the latest version of FusionCharts.
Also, You could implement FusionCharts as an ES6 module, For reference please check https://github.com/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-dist#using-fusioncharts-as-an-es-module.